# How to correct pass php variable to ajax call?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have three files for this. My main php file, functions.php, then my js file.

How do you pass this php variable to js? Here is my code for my **MAIN PHP FILE**

```
function ccss_show_tag_recipes() {

global $post;
global $wp;

$html = '';

$url = home_url( $wp->request );
$path = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);
$pathFragments = explode('/', $path);
$currentPage = end($pathFragments); //I WANT TO PASS THIS TO MY JS FILE


$term_tags = get_terms('cp_recipe_tags'); 
$term_cats = get_terms('cp_recipe_category');

$recipetype = array();
$recipecat = array();

foreach($term_tags as $term) {
    $recipetype[] = $term->slug;
}

foreach($term_cats as $term) {
    $recipecat[] = $term->slug;
}


if ( in_array( $currentPage , $recipecat  ) ) {

        $html = ccss_load_phases($html,$currentPage);

    }

}
```

Here is the function for for css_load_phases();

```
function ccss_load_phases($html = '',$currentPage){
     //CODE HERE etc

    $html .= '<div id="btn-wrapper-'.$termid.'" class="btn-wrapper"><a id="'.$termid.'" class="load-more-btn" href="#">Load more recipes</a></div>';    

}
```

That code above is to trigger the Ajax call, All I can get is the button id.

Here is the AJAX file code:

```
(function($) {
    $(document).on( 'click', 'a.load-more-btn', function( event ) {


    var a = $(this).attr('id'); // I CAN ONLY GET THE ID SINCE IT WAS TRIGGERED BY BUTTON CLICK, how to include $currentPage?

    var button = $(this),
            data = {
            'action': 'ajax_loadmore',
            'termID': a
        };



    event.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            url: ajaxloadmore.ajaxurl,
            data: data, 
            type: 'post',
            beforeSend : function () {
                button.text('Loading...'); // change the button text, you can also add a preloader image
            },
            success: function( result ) {

                 //console.log(data.post_gallery_imgs);

                $('#cooked-recipe-list-'+a+' ').append(result).fadeIn();
                c
                //alert( result );
            },

            complete: function() {
                button.remove(); // if no data, remove the button as well
                //$('body').find('a#'+a+'').remove();
            }
        })
    })

})(jQuery);
```

How Do I pass that $currentPage php variable to my Ajax/Js file? so I can use it here:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_ajax_loadmore', 'my_ajax_loadmore' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_ajax_loadmore', 'my_ajax_loadmore' );

function my_ajax_loadmore() {


    $termID = $_POST['termID']; //ONLY THE BUTTON ID WAS RETRIEVED

}
```

Comment: help anyone? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your function ccss_load_phases, include an input which is hidden.

```
function ccss_load_phases($html = '',$currentPage){

    $html .= '<div id="btn-wrapper-'.$termid.'" class="btn-wrapper">
        <a id="'.$termid.'" class="load-more-btn" href="#">Load more recipes</a>
        <input type="hidden" id="currentPage" value="'.$currentPage.'" />
          </div>';    

}
```

Now you should be able to access this in your javascript by referencing:

`$('#currentPage').val();` or is it `value();`

Answer (score 0):

I usally writte the variable value to an input type hidden, an then acces to with the id or the name

Main php file :

```
echo "<input type='hidden' value='$currentPage' name='currenPage' id='currentPage'>";
```

.js file

```
 $("#currentPage").val()
```